# child class accessing parent's private method?

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, visibility

A user posted a comment on PHP [Visibility manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). It's the second most voted comment. He used this code example:

```
<?php
abstract class base {
    public function inherited() {
        $this->overridden();
    }
    private function overridden() {
        echo 'base';
    }
}

class child extends base {
    private function overridden() {
        echo 'child';
    }
}

$test = new child();
$test->inherited();
?>
```

Output will be "base".

As I understand it: the "child" class inherits the **inherited()** method. Does not inherit the **overridden()** method since it is private but defines its own one instead. But when the **test** object (instance of child class) runs the inherited() method it outputs "base".

So my questions are:

1. How come the child runs a method to which it does not have access?
2. Why it does not run its own redefined method?

Answer (score 3):

Since in the child class you didn't define any `function inherited()`, it'll have to call its parent's method. As the comment you referenced says:

> ... private methods are visible only for the class that defines them and the child class does not see the parent's private methods. ...

That said, since you don't have any public method to reference the child's private method, such as:

```
class child extends base {
    public function inherited() {
        $this->overriden();
    }

    // ...
```

From my point of view, calling `$test->inherited()` would use the scope of its parent, so, what happens if you create an instance of the parent class and call `$this->inherited()`. It'd output *base*.

Try doing what i said above: in the child class, copy and paste the parent's inherited method. It will output *child*.

I'm not sure this is well explained, if it is, maybe it can help you understand a bit more, if it's not, someone may help me improve it.

Comment: Simple summary: if it would output `child`, that'd mean the parent's implementation of `inherited` would call the child's implementation of `overridden`, which clearly violates the "visible only for the class that defines them" rule.

Comment: Yes, if you want `$test->inherited()` to output `child` you just need to create the `inherited()` function in the child class. Thanks for comment @deceze

Comment: Aha, this is about how I (and probably I am not alone) understand inheritance: in fact as a method and property COPYING. So I suppose that when the child class inherits the `inherited` method it actually gets a copy of it. From this point of view the the child calls ITS OWN `inherited` method which then calls the child's `overridden` method and outputs "child".
Well OK, I am realizing that this is not how it actually works. :-)

Comment: I guess it inherits the "reference", so you can be able to call it directly from the child, unless you override it in the child.